# Is there a way to forward Growl notifications to Notification Centre?

Tags: macos, growl

Since there's a lot of apps that support Growl, and only a handful have been updated yet, I'd like to know if there's a way to convert those Growl notifications into Notification Centre notifications.

e.g. some kind of add-on for Growl or a 'proxy' of sorts so that the notifications all come through ML's Notification Centre.

Comment: FYI, Growl 2.0 will support that out of the box.

Comment: I'm kind of hoping by that point I won't need Growl anymore, and that my apps will switch over. NC is near enough to Growl for me that I'll be happier to have one less service running on my laptop.

Comment: That said, Gerry, your comment should be an answer since it's (going to be?) a perfectly valid solution for others!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sure is.**

[**Hiss**](http://collect3.com.au/hiss/) is an app that takes the place of Growl to catch Growl notifications and reroute them to the Notification Center.

One limitation of Hiss, however, is it displays all notifications as coming *from* Growl, rather than the application that actually generated them.

Comment: I was just gonna answer that myself :)

Comment: lol, I was worried that someone was gonna be quicker on the draw.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Though you'd think that an app *developed specifically for Mountain Lion* would have registered with Apple to avoid the "unidentified developer" warning...

Comment: No problem. And I agree, it's gonna make Gatekeeper next to worthless if more people don't hop on board the program. If you just keep bypassing the system, then what's the point?

Answer (score 11):

Since version 2.0, [Growl](http://growl.info) supports "bubbling" notifications to the Notification Center out of the box. You can find the setting for this in the `General` tab of Growl's preferences.

[image: Growl OS X Notifications]

It does come with the same limitations as Hiss though, all notifications appear to be coming from Growl and not the originating app, and clicking them does not appear to launch the expected actions.

Comment: Why did this get down voted? This is the most valid answer for the future when Growl 2.0 will be out of beta. Anyways, have a +1.

Answer (score 4):

In the 2.0 version of the Growl SDK, we introduce Notification Center support. If Growl is not running, the app will post directly to Notification Center. If Growl is running, it's assumed the user wants Growl, and the app will post to Growl.

Here's the fun part.

In Growl 2 there will be a big switch that you can turn to on, to turn on NC support in Growl 2. The way it works is that any app that has the 2.0 version of the framework will be notified that the switch is enabled. Those apps will send to both Growl and Notification Center.

If this switch in Growl is enabled, then the visual notifications portion of Growl will be grayed out and you cannot use them. However, actions will work. So you can send notifications to Prowl/Boxcar/MailMe/etc etc and have Notification Center be the visual notifications.

Comment: Since Growl has now been updated to version 2.0, this is now the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the interim here is another method to forward Growl to Notification Center:
https://github.com/stigi/MountainGrowl
Notifications are still shown as coming from Growl rather than the originating app. In use, it's a bit easier to deal with than Hiss, which seems buggy at present.